# Why is math.sqrt(r**2 - (x-h)**2) + k returning a ValueError: math domain error

Tags: python, math

```
def drawCircle(h, k, r):
    #(x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 = r^2
    for x in range(screen.Width):
        y = (math.sqrt(r**2 - (x-h)**2) + k)
        if y % 1 == 0:
            screen.Set(x, int(y), "X")

drawCircle(0, 0, 5)
```

screen is a simple console renderer library that I wrote that positions items in a 2D array with the most top-left corner being (0,0)

Comment: y % 1 == 0 seems trivially set to 0 as well. Do you want to do something different?

Comment: This is not really the best way to draw a circle. Even if you sort the problem with sqrt out you will find it will miss a lot of points. A classic method is the [Midpoint circle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) but in general its best to use a library call if possible.

Comment: For `x` values outside of the [h-r, h+r] range, there is no circle and no y value, so you get a `ValueError`. Just catch that error and ignore that `x` value: `except ValueError: continue`

Comment: @zvone there is probably no need to `continue`, since once `x-h` is high enough, I think the result of `r**2 - (x-h)**2` will always be negative. In that case, it might be better to just `break`.

Comment: @elethan yes, that optimizes the algorithm, it is even better to just change the range to the reasonable one. my intention was a minimal intervention ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is my guess that the result in parens that you are `sqrt`ing ends up being negative at some point. If and when it does, the error you are seeing will be raised when you try to take the square root of that number.

To confirm this, try saving `r**2 - (x-h)**2` to a variable and printing it before taking the `sqrt`.

Comment: I did what you recommended and this was the output:

25,  
24,  
21,  
16,  
9, 
0, 
-11,  

it seems that when my loop reaches the 7th iteration it outputs a negative number I will look into this.

Thanks for the answer

Comment: I would assume that if screen.width is more than 5, then it tries to take the square root of -11. So maybe closing the loop for extraneous values

if abs (x-h) > r: # maybe check if x > h too if you need to
    break;

Comment: @BenKosten Checkout the the comments on this question for a possible solution to your problem if you haven't come up with one yet. Also, don't forget to accept this answer if it answered your original question ;)